# Rails Form accept only integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

This might be a noobish question but I have a `number_field` that can only accept a value between 3 and 5 and only whole numbers(integer).

Now I've managed to get the range right with max and min but I can still fill in 3,5 for example.  Is there any way to set this up?

I've been looking at the documentation but can't find anything. Also I don't want to use any gems like simple_form because of a template I use.

Comment: You need to add a rails validation that demands an integer.  Google rails validations and more specifically "numericality"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps in your model you could use a validatation?

Something like

```
   validates :number_field, numericality: { only_integer: true }
```

More information here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality

Then, if you want to provide feedback to users you can put some code in the create section of the controller.

```
respond_to do |format|
if @xyz.save
#success
else
format.html { render :new }
format.json { render json: @xyz.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
```

Look on here or elsewhere for actioncontroller errors for more info.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In you number_field add ", in: 3..5"

here is a sample from my project's code:

'inputWidth', :value => 2, in: 1..100%>

In forms it will only accept the whole numbers within that range.